# Getting an "to" must be a string, "to" must be an array error for sendPushNotificationsAsync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

I’m currently using [expo-server-sdk](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node) to send a multiple push notifications, but getting the following error:

> { Error: “value” must be an object, “value” at position 0 fails
>   because [child “to” fails because [“to” must be a string, “to” must be
>   an array]].

Valid push tokens are passed to expo.chunkPushNotifications, but when chunk is passed to expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk), I get the error message mentioned above:

```
(async () => {
  for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
})();
```

The chunk is in the following form:

```
[ { to:
     { notificationToken: 'ExponentPushToken[some_push_token]' },
    sound: 'default',
    body: 'This is a test notification',
    data: { withSome: 'data' } },
]
```

which means the chunks is in the from of an array of an array of objects:

```
[ [ { to: [Object],
      sound: 'default',
      body: 'This is a test notification',
      data: [Object] },
]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `to` needs to be a `string` or `string[]` and you are sending `object` here.

Try changing your payload to

```
    [
        {
            to: 'ExponentPushToken[some_push_token]',
            sound: 'default',
            body: 'This is a test notification',
            data: { withSome: 'data' },
        },
    ]
```